# Question about modifying response body object using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, axios

Apologies if formatting is incorrect. I'm currently working on making a request to a 3rd party api using axios through an express router. I'm attempting to use transformResponse to modify the the response object so I can better use the results. The problem is when called like this, node responds with 'typeError: cannot convert undefined or null to object'

```
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
axios.get(`${stockURL}?symbol=googl`, {
    params: {
        function: 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY',
        apikey: ALPHA_KEY,
        outputsize: 'full'
    },
    transformResponse: [function (data) {
        // Do whatever you want to transform the data
        function fixKeys(obj) {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                let newKey = key.split('.')[1].trim();
                //dynamic form of obj.newKey
                obj[newKey] = obj[key];
                delete obj[key];
            });
            return obj;
        }
        //the main object with all dates by day
        // let fullData = data[stockDay.json];
        let fullData = data['Time Series (Daily)'];

        let arrayData = [];
        // adds a key value pair for the date, with the date of the stock quote, 
        //and then deletes the key 'Time Series (Daily)'
        Object.keys(fullData).map(function (key) {
            let obj = {};
            obj = fixKeys(fullData[key]);
            obj['date'] = key;
            arrayData.push(obj);
        });
        //current days data
        todayData = arrayData[0];
        //get 52 week high/low
        let arrayLow = [];
        let arrayHigh = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 365 && i < arrayData.length; i++) {
            arrayLow.push(parseInt(arrayData[i].low));
            arrayHigh.push(parseInt(arrayData[i].high));
        }
        todayData['tlow'] = Math.min.apply(null, arrayLow);
        todayData['thigh'] = Math.max.apply(null, arrayLow);
        return todayData;
    }]
})
    .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload.todayData)
        res.json(payload.todayData);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Something went wrong while querying Alphavantage'
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: It would help if you shared in which line you're receiving the error.

Comment: Sounds like one of your Object.keys() is getting a null value. Check if there's a line with the error or console log before. fullData to make sure it looks like what you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for the lack of clarification but it was the Object.keys value that was the problem. The data returned was still json so it didn't id the data as an object since it was a string.